# On the number of permutations on $n$ letters with the greatest cycle length of $k$

Tags: probability, abstract-algebra, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutation-cycles

I am trying to understand the theory ["On the number of permutations on $n$ objects with the greatest cycle length of $k$"](https://books.google.de/books?id=Z9kmN_jJ03cC&lpg=PA211&ots=-q7OZt28nM&dq=%22On%20the%20number%20of%20permutations%20of%22%20%22objects%20with%20greatest%20cycle%20length%22&pg=PA211#v=onepage&q&f=false) by Solomon W Golomb and Peter Gaal.

Let $L_{k,n}$ denotes the number of permutation on $n$ letters having a greatest cycle of length $k$ . I want to understand the formula

$$L_{k,n}=\sum_{j=1}^{\lfloor n/k \rfloor}\frac{1}{j!k^j}\frac{n!}{(n-kj)!}\sum_{t=1}^{min(k-1,n-kj)}L_{t,n-kj} \quad \quad (1 <k\le n)$$

I am considering the case $\frac n4<k \le \frac n3$ . Then

$$L_{k,n}=\frac {n!}{k} \left \{ 1-\sum_{j=1}^{n-2k}\frac{1}{k+j}+\sum_{j=1}^{n-3k-1}\sum_{l=1}^{n-3k-j} \frac{1}{2(k+j)(k+l)}        -\frac {1}{2k} \bigg[ 1-\sum_{j=1}^{n-3k}\frac{1}{k+j} -\frac{1}{3k}\bigg] \right \}$$

By the given restriction on $n$ there can be at most three cycles of lentgth $k$

I think the authors considered the following types of permutations along with different categories of greatest cycle length .

$(a)$  Permutations having one cycle of lenth $k$.

$(b)$ Permutations having one cycle of lenth $k$ and two cycles of length greater than $k$

$(c)$ Permutations having one cycle of length $k$ and one cycle of length greater than $k$

$(d)$ Permutations having two cycle of length $k$ and one cycle of length greater than $k$

$(e)$ Permutations having two cycle of length $k$

$(f)$ Permutations having three cycles of lenth $k$

The number of permutations in category $(a)$ are ${n \choose k }(k-1)!(n-k)!=\frac{n!}{k}$

In category $(b)$ , let the two cycles of length greater than $k$ be of length $k+j$ and $k+l$

We want to find the bounds on $j$ and $l$. Clearly $j,l\ge 1$.

Now, $k+(k+1)+(k+j)\le n$

$\implies j\le n-3k-1$

And , $k+(k+j)+(k+l)\le n$

$\implies l\le n-3k-j$

Then the number of permutations having a cycle of length $k$ and cycles of length $(k+j)$ and $(k+l)$ is given by

$$\frac 12 {n \choose k}{n-k  \choose k+j}{n-2k-j \choose k+l}(k-1)!(k+j-1)!(k+l-1)!(n-3k-j-l)!$$

$$=\frac 12\frac{n!}{k}\frac{1}{(k+j)(k+l)}$$

Not sure why is the  factor $\frac 12$ present. I think its because exactly after $j$   covers half the way between $1$ and $(n-3k-1)$ , the pairs of values of $k+j$ and $k+l$ interchange with respect to the first half. (Generally we are dividing by $k!$ when we are selecting $k$ groups of equals size from a given number of objects (say) $n$)

In category $(c)$, let the cycles  of length greater than $k$ be $(k+j)$ . Then $j\ge1$ and

$k+(k+j)\le n$

$\implies j\le n-2k$

So , number of permutations having a cycle of length $k$ and a cycle of length greater than $(k+j)$ is given by

$${n \choose k}{n-k \choose k+j}(k-1)!(k+j-1)!(n-2k-j)!$$

$$=\frac {n!}{k}\frac {1}{k+j}$$

Similarly the other terms in the expression,

I understand that the overall aim  here is to eliminate from the set of all permutations having a cycle of length $k$ , other unnecessary permutations having two cycles of length $k$ (because of overcounting) or cycles of length greater than $k$.

But I don't understand the actual interplay between the plus and minuses signs between the  different terms in the expression and how does that help in leading to the general formula.

I am self studying and apologise for my seemingly confused way of writing.Thanks in advance .

$UPDATE :$   Here's one idea I have got after revisiting the theory today ..

Let $P(\underbrace{k,k,\ldots,k}_{t\text{-times}},k+j,k+l,...k+p) $ denote the set of permutations having some $t$ cycles of length $k$ and other cycles of length greater than $k$

Then if $\frac n4<k \le \frac n3$ , we have

$L_{k,n}=|P(k)|-|P(k,k+j)|+|P(k,k+j,k+l)|-\left \{ |P(k,k)|-|P(k,k,k+j)|-\big [   |P(k,k,k)| \big ]   \right \}     $

So the brackets are somehow going nested starting with $P(k),P(k,k)...$ in the expression along with the alternate signs as one goes within a chain of fixed number of cycles of length $k$   and increasing the number of cycles of length greater than $k$ along the chain .

OK I  try writing out the $L_{k,n}$ for the case $\frac n5<k \le \frac n4$

$$L_{k,n}=|P(k)|-|P(k,k+j)|+|P(k,k+j,k+l)|-|P(k,k+j,k+l,k+m)|-\left \{ |P(k,k)|-|P(k,k,k+j)|+|P(k,k,k+j,k+l)|-\big [ |P(k,k,k)|-  |P(k,k,k,k+j)| -|P(k,k,k,k)|\big ]   \right \}     $$

Which turns out to be matching with the formula provided in the linked text. So I guess my understanding is correct.

Now coming to the general formula , I think the upper bound for $j=\lfloor n/k   \rfloor$ says how many maximum $k$ length cycles can be formed from the $n$ objects .

The expression $$\frac{1}{j!k^j}\frac{n!}{(n-kj)!}=\frac{\left \{(k-1) !\right \}^j}{j!}{n \choose k}{{n-k} \choose k}\dots {{n-kj+k} \choose k}$$

tells how many permutations on $n$ objects have $j$ cycles of length $k$

Now , for each of the above permutations (for a fixed $j$), the inner sum tells us how many permutations (on the remaining $(n-kj)$ objects )are there of greatest cycle length from $1$ upto  $(k-1)$ or $(n-kj)$ whichever is smaller.

So the general formula gives us  all permutations having a certain no of cycles each of length $k$ along with cycles of length shorter than $k$ thus giving all permutations having greatest cycle of length $k$

Suggestions ??

Comment: I fundamentally don't understand something about your post: you begin by writing "I want to understand [some particular recursive formula]" but after the word "Then" you do not have anything recursive, you have a totally different formula.  So which thing are you really trying to understand?

Comment: (I kept reading and got as far as your proof that the number of permutations with a $k$-cycle is $\frac{n!}{k}$.  Since that is not true under either natural interpretation "with a $k$-cycle" (neither "with exactly one $k$-cycle" nor "with at least one $k$-cycle" -- for example, the number of permutations in $S_3$ with exactly one $1$-cycle is $3$ and the number of permutations with at least one $1$-cycle is $4$, and neither of these numbers is $\frac{3!}{1}$), I gave up before I got to the end.)

Comment: @JBL  For your first question , the two formulas being different in nature (one is recursive and other is not ) is very clear. But the fact that if we plug in the condition  $n/(3+1) < k \le n/3 $ in the recursive general formula , we get a particular non-recursive formula for $L_{3,n}$ may not be very easy to derive . So I wanted to understand both the formula because they are both related and in fact that's how the authors  go where they show deriving the formula for some "special" values of $k$ and then to general formula because the former is easier to grasp at first .

Comment: @JBL The interpretation "with a $k$- cycle " is "at least one $k$- cycle " .I edited my post to mention that the general recursive formula holds for $1 <k \le n$  since  $L_{1,n}=1$ for all $n$

Comment: Again, certainly not: there are 9 (not 12) permutations in $S_4$ with at least one 2-cycle.  (This is just not fixable.)

Comment: I do not think your question is well formulated: to me, it looks like an unseparable mishmash of multiple different questions.  I think you should try to rewrite it to focus on a single question that could be answered (e.g.: how does one derive the recurrence [removing the stuff about the other formula]?  or: given the recurrence, how does one derive the other formula [removing the attempts to derive it directly]?  or: how does one derive the other formula [removing the stuff about the recurrence]?).

Comment: I should say: I can tell you what $\frac{n!}{k}$ actually means in this context, but because this question is such a mishmash, I can't tell if that information is related to an answer.  Specifically, $\frac{n!}{k}$ is the number of pairs $(\sigma, c)$ where $\sigma$ is a permutation in $S_n$ and $c$ is a particular $k$-cycle of $\sigma$.  Equivalently, it is the total number of $k$-cycles among all permutations in $S_n$.

Comment: Yes it made sense to me with the interpretation of $\frac{n!}k$ because basically for your counter example of $S_4$ , the permutations $(1 3)(2,4) , (1 4)(2,3), (1 2)(3 4)$   are each counted twice (once for each $k-$ cycle that a permutation has ) and thus we get that value by this algorithm  $1)$  Check if any permutation has a $k-$ cycle . $2)$ Increase the count for each $k-$ cycle present in a particular permutation . Great !! . So we need to keep a check on this count ..right ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146171/discussion-between-user-492177-and-jbl).